# Why Clang copies the constant arrays in LLVM IR?

Tags: c, optimization, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I have this piece of code to demonstrate:

```
int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char a[8] = {65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72};
  printf("a %s", a);
}
```

What i expect would be that this array will be place as constant one in some place and
we will just copy the pointer not its content. Here is what Clang does at -O0 level optimization:

```
@__const.main.a = private unnamed_addr constant [8 x i8] c"ABCDEFGH", align 1
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [5 x i8] c"a %s\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main(i32 noundef %0, i8** noundef %1) #0 {
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i8**, align 8
  %5 = alloca [8 x i8], align 1
  store i32 %0, i32* %3, align 4
  store i8** %1, i8*** %4, align 8
  %6 = bitcast [8 x i8]* %5 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* align 1 %6, i8* align 1 getelementptr inbounds ([8 x i8], [8 x i8]* @__const.main.a, i32 0, i32 0), i64 8, i1 false)
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds [8 x i8], [8 x i8]* %5, i64 0, i64 0
  %8 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* noundef getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i8], [5 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i8* noundef %7)
  ret i32 0
}

; Function Attrs: argmemonly nofree nounwind willreturn
declare void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* noalias nocapture writeonly, i8* noalias nocapture readonly, i64, i1 immarg) #1
```

It creates %5 and then copies the content using "llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64" internal function into %5. Why does it do that ?

I have played around send the produced llvm ir file to clang again and at O1 level optimization clang produced the following:

```
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [5 x i8] c"a %s\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: nofree noinline nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main(i32 noundef %0, i8** nocapture noundef readnone %1) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
  %3 = alloca i64, align 8
  store i64 5208208757389214273, i64* %3, align 8
  %4 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* noundef nonnull dereferenceable(1) getelementptr inbounds ([5 x i8], [5 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i64* noundef nonnull %3)
  ret i32 0
}
```

This makes more sense to me than the o0 level optimization. I have tested huge structs too and Clang still uses llvm.memcpy to copy the content. What is wrong with considering 'char a[8]' as 'char**' since there will be no copying and moving things and it will be deleted if not referenced.

My guess is that at -O0 level, Clang compiler has to comply with the definitions of the C language design. Since the type created is 'char a[8]' then it has to 'alloca' [8 x i8]. But when you see the optimizations on llvm ir file then that 'llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64' does some magic to optimize the code.

Why does clang copies it at -O0 level ? How should i approach this ?

Comment: That code leads to *undefined behavior*, so the compiler is allowed to do anything it wants.

Comment: Since there's no optimization, and `a` isn't actually a string literal constant but a local array with automatic storage duration, there's no reason nor justification for the compiler to replace it with a pointer to same (`a` has to be initialized, `a` and its constant initialization source data aren't the same thing, `printf` is at least somewhat opaque to the compiler, etc.)

Comment: Without optimization, the compiler doesn't take into account that `printf` has specific standard-defined behavior.  So for all it knows, `printf` might modify the buffer passed to it, and then call `main` recursively (this is legal in C).  If that were so, then passing a pointer to the static "original" data, instead of to a copy, would be wrong.  There does have to be a fresh copy made on every call to `main`, because we don't know how many such calls there might be.

Comment: no literal, UB & no optimization - the time you spent analyzing it was simply wasted.

Comment: @NateEldredge forget about printf. thats there to show it doesnt delete format string. also same behaviour happens in other functions too. its about how clang allocates stuff.

Comment: @SupportUkraine i was trying to understand the design decisions. like it or not it matters how clang initializes stuff and its really not an easy decision to make.

Comment: @Hasturkun yes i agree for this example. try it out with different structs and you will see it does the similar things.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid the copy (i.e initialization, which is present in both cases), you could make the array `static` and/or `static const`, in which case it wouldn't need to occupy any space in the function's stack, so wouldn't require copying/init inline. Your original expectation is incorrect in any case, having no optimization inhibits optimizations such as direct inline initialization for such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a local variable and Clang always produces an `alloca` for that. Then you filled it with data, and the data is an aggregate, so Clang emits the aggregate data to a global variable and a memcpy to copy the bytes. Note that `char a[8]` is mutable, if your code had `a[5]++;` then it must change only this copy of the data that is local to the function and the original data must still exist so that the next time the function is run the variable gets initialized with the original value again.

You could point out that your code doesn't mutate the contents of `a`, but clang doesn't work like that. It turns each Clang AST node into LLVM IR as simply as it can. That kind of analysis is left to LLVM's optimizations.

Comment: get it. so its about consistency. thank you so much. you might say "daa of course it is" but there are so many work arounds in softwares that it gets confusing.